# uniform continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

how to prove uniform continuity of, $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$where $x\in(0,1)$, I was trying ti find a $\lambda$ s.t.$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-\frac{\sin(y)}{y}\right|\le\lambda|x-y|$$but i am unable to find it.

Comment: Do you know that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? Hint: for $x \in (0, 1)$, $|\sin(x)| < x$.

Comment: the given set is not compact...@ ayman hourieh

Comment: $[0, 1]$ is compact and it contains $(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$
 one can define a continuous function $f: [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as

$$f (x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$$
with $f(0) = 1$.

Now, by Heine-Cantor theorem, $f$ is continuous on a compact set, hence it is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. This implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

Comment: does uniform continuity on a closed set implies uniform continuity on the open set?

Comment: @sapta Sure; the dependence on the set comes in from a universal quantifier, so if it is true for $A$ then it is true for any subset of $A$.